# jpeg colours not displaying correctly in Chrome, FF and Safari

Tags: color-profile, jpg

We seem to be experiencing issues with some of our jpeg product images displaying colours differently across different browsers. (When wrong, they look as if their hues have been shifted and vibrancy has been turned up)

IE11 looks to be showing the correct colours we'd expect, but FF, Chrome and in some instances Safari (iPhone5s and iPad2) are showing the weird versions of our colours?

**NOTE:** Left image is Internet Explorer 11   - Right image is Google Chrome 49.0.2623.110 m (But also FF + Safari on iPad + iPhone shows similar colours as this)

[image: Image on left is IE11, image right is Chrome 49.0.2623.110 m]

Answer (score 4):

Your *.jpg file has most probably a CMYK (print) colour profile embedded. Lots of browsers will then distort the colours. Try and re-save the files with an RGB profile and you'll be right as rain.

Comment: specifically [sRGB IEC 61966-2-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB).

Comment: I've just looked at how our graphics teams photoshop export to web is setup. When they opened the photograph the image opens in the CMYK mode but the export for the web has the checkbox ticked for convert to sRGB. I've asked him to change the mode to RGB and save for web again to see if this resolves the issue. Will post back with findings

Comment: Ok, just got them back from Graphics and although there are slight differences in colours neither are like the extremely saturated and hue shifted examples above?

Comment: Any color conversion will always give you slight differences. Ideally the image should have been made in RGB to begin with (assuming it's only destined for web use) otherwise you're stuck with the fact that you can't reliably exactly match converted colors.

Comment: Found this tool which brings back a lot of information on the file: http://metapicz.com/#landing?imgsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.galttoys.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F02%2FTwo-in-One-Playnest-Box-3D.jpg

Comment: Also I found this question that sounds similar and seems to be a good point of reference. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30500/why-do-my-photoshop-designs-turn-neon-when-i-upload-them-online